# react-native app error when try and test in emulator(?)

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

I get this error below whenever I try to test the app after typing the command npx react-native run-android. I tried setting paths in environmental variables. But still doesn't work I tried reinstalling react-native but still does not work. I tried to reinstall JDK from java but finally, the app still does not run in the emulator. Any feedback is appreciated :)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_masked-view:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271 contains a valid JDK installation.

- Try:
  Run with --stack trace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

PS C:\vibenote-texting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to update your PATH variables.

```
To set the PATH variable permanently, add the full path of the jdk1.7.0\bin directory to the PATH variable. Typically, this full path looks something like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin. Set the PATH variable as follows on Microsoft Windows:

Click Start, then Control Panel, then System.

Click Advanced, then Environment Variables.

Add the location of the bin folder of the JDK installation for the PATH variable in System Variables. The following is a typical value for the PATH variable:

C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin
```

[From the docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#path)

Comment: I tried this will try again following your instructions will let you know if works. Thank you for sharing :)

Comment: As you can see I set the path: Accordingly but still does not work. any feed back is appreciated 

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\jdk-15.0.1\bin

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Comment: @martin that path was just a place holder - you will need to find your own valid path to your  installation of JDK and set it to that

Comment: I can't seem to find the correct path what I'm I doing wrong?

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\java.exe

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the    
location of your Java installation.

Comment: I tried redirecting the path several  times I still getting the same error  
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Comment: I fixed it this is the correct path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\jre Thank you :)

Comment: You are Awesome :)